# Count Number of Json Array that is Filtered from another Json Array

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I have two json that I need to get nested using Angular cli 6.0

I'm new to angular so I need help..

Json 1

```
[{"Name": "Fields1",
"DFields":["Fields1_1","Fields1_2"]
},
{"Name": "Fields2",
"DFields":["Fields2_1"]
}]
```

Json 2

```
[
{"Id": "1", "Fields1_1": 1 , "Fields1_2": 1, "Fields2_1: 1},
{"Id": "2", "Fields1_1": 1 , "Fields1_2": 0, "Fields2_1: 1} 
{"Id": "3", "Fields1_1": 1 , "Fields1_2": 1, "Fields2_1: null} 
]
```

What is the faster way to loop through fields and count their corresponding data.. which count should be not null or zero..

the sample should return an array of..

```
Fields1_1 = 3
Fields1_2 = 2
Fields2_1 = 2
```

please remind that these fields are dynamic and can be change depending on json

Comment: Please share some code or approach that you have taken to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJs v6 solution :)

```js
    const json1 = [
  { "Name": "Fields1", "DFields": ["Fields1_1", "Fields1_2"] },
  { "Name": "Fields2", "DFields": ["Fields2_1"] }
];

const json2 = [
  { "Id": "1", "Fields1_1": 1, "Fields1_2": 1, "Fields2_1": 1 },
  { "Id": "2", "Fields1_1": 1, "Fields1_2": 0, "Fields2_1": 1 },
  { "Id": "3", "Fields1_1": 1, "Fields1_2": 5, "Fields2_1": null }
];

from(json2).pipe(
  map(obj => Object.keys(obj).map(k => { return { key: k, val: obj[k] } })),
  flatMap(kvPairArray => from(kvPairArray)),
  groupBy(kvPair => kvPair.key),
  filter(group => json1.map(a => a.DFields).reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []).includes(group.key)),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(
    filter(groupEntry => groupEntry.val !== null && groupEntry.val !== 0),
    reduce<{key: string, val: number},number>((acc, groupEntry) => acc + groupEntry.val, 0),
    map(count => {
      return {
        key: group.key,
        count: count
      };
    })
  )),
  toArray()
).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: import { map, filter, tap, flatMap, mergeMap, reduce, groupBy} from 'rxjs/operators'; ---  am I missing something? Cannot find toarray and from

Comment: import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from'; import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: it still says no exported member 'from' but upon checking the path was correct, do you have an email or some sort? please I want to know more..

Comment: Which rxjs version do you use?

Comment: # RxJS 6 Stable says on my READ me

Comment: it seems my import some comments above is wrong anyway. from has to be imported directly from 'rxjs': import { from } from 'rxjs';
but i hope you tried this before asking :)

Comment: It works. although I have a typescript error
You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
I encapsulate the code within a class ==>
 BindData(questionArr, dataArr){ // code here }
  ngOnInit(): void{
this.BindData(this._questionsArray,this._dataArray);
 }

Comment: does it work if you just copy paste my code snippet into your ngOnInit function?

Comment: then you are doing something wrong. See this blitzstack. Its working fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aj8jtd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: its now working its just having a problem when getting the json from an service which returns Observable<array[]>.. also I think I misinterpret the logic behind the count.. it should count the number of ID instead the total.. so if I change "Fields1_1": 1 to 2 , it should be still 3 and not 4

Comment: Here is my code https://angular-fya5of.stackblitz.io I know its kind of ugly, I comment the two class that has error.. but it logs the same output

Comment: you are calling BindData when the results from api have not arrived. You need to bundle the two requests and in subscribe fuction call BindData with the results. I fixed your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjgfyc

Comment: thanks a lot shifu, I learned a lot, although I have to learn these rsjx let me know if you have a good tutorial link in mind

Comment: a good starting point is https://www.learnrxjs.io/ Just read through and try out the snippets from there. Then just try to use rxjs in your app. Have fun ;)

Comment: thanks! I'm reading the basic functions of rxjs. Anyway I know this is much, could you tip me on what should I use if I wanted to push the result you created into the first array. I edited my blitzstack and added a comment on what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: well, this gets a little bit creepy now and there are probably better solutions, but i integrated it in your stackblitz in a way you can easily add it to your initial questionarray if you want: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbjx3g

Comment: these nested maps are a bit confusing to understand but thanks again for the fix I'll get back to reading each line one by one

Comment: Hi Alexander is it possible to base group key on DValues from questionArr? so that every value from DValues is covered even there's no count it will be going to be zero instead?